# mongodb/meteor collection check if subdocument field exists when field is a variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to use something as follows

```
collection.find({"myField."+variable : {$exists: true})
```

But obviously that doesn't work because the collections doesn't take strings. Instead, I tried building a a fully query string in JSON but that won't parse correctly because I'm just searching for a field name and not an entire object

```
var qry = '{"myField.'+variable+'"}'; //no go
```

I've also tried the meteor collection fields logic

```
var qry = 'myField.'+variable; 
collection.find({}, {fields: {qry: 1}})
```

to no avail. I know that a query can take a JSON object but I'm not sure how to write this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using bracket notation

```
var fieldQuery = {};
fieldQuery["myField"+variable] = {$exists: true};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation

Comment: thanks, I actually solved it doing this:    var query = {};
  query['myField.'+variable] = null;

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
var selector = {};
selector["myField." + variable] = {$exists: true};
Collection.find(selector);
```

Comment: what if I wanted to find something with multiple selectors? for example, `find(x: false, y: true, z: {$exists: false})`

Comment: The example you gave should be: `find({x: false, y: true, z: {$exists: false}})`. As you can see the selector is a single object - just append whatever fields you need to it. Working from my answer you could initialize `selector` to be `{x: false, y: true}` and then dynamically append `z` later before the call to `find`. If that isn't clear you can give more details and I can update the answer or you can ask another question.

Comment: I tried appending the query object by just defining another field and value. So I did `selector[myField.variable]={$exists: true};` then I did `selector['myOtherField'] = value` and did `Collection.find(selector)` . If this is how it should be done then maybe there's something else wrong but I just want to know if its correct syntax. When I log the selector object, I see that the first field is of type Object but the second field is just `myOtherField: value` so I'm not sure if that is the issue. I also tried building a query string using the `$and` selector. Please update the answer, thanks!

Comment: What you are doing _sounds_ correct, so I suspect the actual problem is just with the selector, rather than how you are building it. I'd recommend opening a new question with all of the necessary details. Show everything you tried and the exact output you are looking for.